# Don't understand cause of TypeError when trying to use my is_descending() function

Tags: python, sequence

Function is_descending, which accepts one parameter list and checks if it is a descending sequence i.e. the first element in the list must be bigger than the second, the second bigger than the third, the third bigger than the fourth, etc... The return value is `True`/`False`.

```
def is_descending(a):
  for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] < a[i + 1]:
     return False
    elif a[i] > a[i + 1]:
       return True


assert is_descending(3, 4) == False
assert is_descending(5, 5) == False
assert is_descending(10, 1) == True
assert is_descending(10, 8, 7, 6, 1, -10, -20) == True
assert is_descending(10, 8, 7, 6,6, 1, -10, -20) == False
assert is_descending(1) == True
```

terminal writes:

```
TypeError: is_descending() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any advice on how to edit my code? I want to work with only 1 parameter.

Comment: Two things - wrap arguments to list `is_descending([3, 4])` (or even better, tuple) and check again your function itself, as it always iterates only once.

Comment: If you really want to pass in multiple parameters rather than a single `list`, you need to do `def is_descending(*a)` to automatically wrap all of them into a tuple. [Arbitrary Argument Lists docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). You still need to fix the loop and logic, as others have mentioned.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs `a` to be a list.
Instead of `is_descending(3, 4)` that passes 2 parameters (2 integers), use `is_descending([3, 4])`.

Also the function should only return True once the whole list has been checked. Here only the first check matters as using `return` stops the loop without checking for other pairs of values.

Instead you can remove the `elif` block and return True outside of the for loop to wait for all the checks to be passed successfully.

Also a simpler way to achieve this would be to check if the list is sorted in reversed order (i.e. does it change after being sorted):

```
def is_reversed(a):
   return a == sorted(a, reverse=True)
```